# Rails routes inside resources :blah do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes, custom-routes

So far my routes.rb file looks something like this:

```
resources :games do
  resources :planets do
    member do
      get 'index' as: :play_game
    end
  end
end
```

which creates these (when I check rake routes)

```
play_game_game_planet GET    /games/:game_id/planets/:id/index(.:format) planets#index
         game_planets GET    /games/:game_id/planets(.:format)           planets#index
                      POST   /games/:game_id/planets(.:format)           planets#create
     new_game_planet  GET    /games/:game_id/planets/new(.:format)       planets#new
    edit_game_planet  GET    /games/:game_id/planets/:id/edit(.:format)  planets#edit
         game_planet  GET    /games/:game_id/planets/:id(.:format)       planets#show
                      PATCH  /games/:game_id/planets/:id(.:format)       planets#update
                      PUT    /games/:game_id/planets/:id(.:format)       planets#update
                      DELETE /games/:game_id/planets/:id(.:format)       planets#destroy
```

but the path I want is (similar to the second line)

```
play_game GET    /games/:game_id/planets(.:format)           planets#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the `game_planets /games/:game_id/planets(.:format)           planets#index` route defined above -- the named route for which is `game_planets`. So I assume what you're wanting is a different name for the named route?

If that's what you're after and you can't be advised otherwise (i.e. other Rails developers looking at this would wonder why the non-standard named route structure) then you can do this:

```
resources :games do
  resources :planets
end

get 'games/:game_id/planets', 'planets#index', as: 'play_game'
```

This essentially creates a duplicate route with a special named route. But I'd recommend against this because:

1. Index actions should use a plural named route (so at least use `as: 'play_games'`)
2. It's not standard. The named route `play_game` would make me think there was a `PlayController` that had a nested `Game` controller and that this would be a `show` action requiring a `play` object passed into it.

Comment: Exactly, when i named it inside the resources block, it would add things to it, but doing it outside like that works well